# optimize.curve_fit: how to bound one parameter respective to another?

Tags: python, scipy, curve-fitting

When doing (ad hoc example)

```
from scipy import optimize

def fit_func(x, a, b):
    return a*x + b

optimize.curve_fit(fit_func, x_data, y_data)
```

how can I put bounds like `a>b`? I know the option `bounds`, but it appears it does accept only explicit numbers.

Maybe some `if` in the definition of `fit_func`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try with a workaround, instead of defining the function as:

```
def fit_func1(x, a, b):
    return a*x + b
```

with constraint `a>b`, you can do:

```
def fit_func2(x, this_much_a_is_bigger_than_b, b):
    return (a+this_much_a_is_bigger_than_b)*x + b
```

with constraint `this_much_a_is_bigger_than_b > 0`, `0` being an explicit number, and `fit_func2` function is equivalent to the `fit_func1` from a mathematical perspective.

Then you can have:

```
a = b + this_much_a_is_bigger_than_b
b = b
```

Answer (score 2):

Curce_fit only supports box constraints (via least_squares). There are workarounds, but I'd rather change variables to e.g `a` and `b-a`

Comment: or no constraints at all by `b` --> `b ` and `a` --> `b + a**2`